# JQUERY: Finding the form element

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages

**BEFORE CHAOS**

I used to have this one...

at the head part

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(function() { $("form.openid:eq(0)").openid(); });</script>
```

in the jquery.openid.js

```
var direct = function () {
    var $li = $(this);

    $this.unbind('submit').submit(function() {
      $id.val($this.find("li.highlight span").text());
    });
    $this.submit();
    return false;
  };
```

and in the body part

```
<form class="openid" method="post" action="/Login.xhtml?ReturnUrl="> 
  <div>
   <ul class="providers">  
    <li class="direct" title="Google"> <img src="images/googleW.png" alt="icon" />
   </ul>
  </div>  
</form>
```

which works like a charm.

**AFTER CHAOS**

Now since i would like to add the all above as content in an ASP.NET page i made the appropriate changes

at the head part in The MasterPage

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(function () { $("#test.openidd").openid(); });</script>
```

in the body part, i added the div with `id=test` and class equal to `openidd`.

```
<div id ="test" class="openidd">
  <ul class="providers">
  <li class="direct" title="Google"> <img src="images/google.png" />     
  </ul>
</div>
```

So what changes should i make to the `jquery.openid.js` to make it work?

I mean in the first case the `$this` refers to `form.openid:eq(0)`
In the second case the `$this` refers to `#text.openidd` and the form is never submitted.

I guess something like this one `$this.FindParentForm` exists in JQUERY, but i have no clue!

Please keep your answers as simple as possible, since i am a newbie

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**
From the answers i have seen so far, i guess or i have not set my question clear or i am soooo newbie. I added the div tag as enclosure for the elements. The form contains other `<li>`'s etc that jquery messes with. And i would not like that! That's why in my post i believe that the work has to be done in the `jquery.openid.js` file... something like

```
$this.GETParentFORM.unbind('submit').submit(function() {
   $id.val($this.GETParentFORM.find("li.highlight span").text());
   });
$this.GETParentFORM.submit();
```

Comment: I do not understand what function you call here $("form.openid:eq(0)").openid(), and where you call the function var 'direct = function () {...'

Comment: Why are you desperately try to use __this__ ? instead of using __eq()__ or such things, you may try to pass a variable when you call openid(), maybe unique id of the related form like __.openid(<formid>)__ and use that id within openid function instead of __$this__

Comment: This will get you the parent form: http://carnotaurus.tumblr.com/post/3121098288/communication-between-frames-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CODE**

```
$(this).parents('form#myId')...
```

**EXAMPLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/ngdcs/

Answer (score 1):

One thing to look out for in ASP.NET with jQuery is that any control that has `runat="server"` will have an auto-generated ID based on the original ID. Just saying, especially if you're planning to select via IDs on your jQuery.

Having said that, supposedly, there's only one form in any ASP.NET page (the one located on your MasterPage). So to select that, all you actually have to do is go

```
$('form')
```

but if you want to go your route, I'd use

```
$('#test.openidd').closest('form')
```

Comment: Like I said, ASP.NET pages should only have one form... so doesn't `$('form').openid();` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably change it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(function () { $("#test.openidd").parents('form').openid(); });</script>
```

Although I think it would be better to give your form an id like:

```
<form id="submitForm5" ...>
```

and then change the javascript code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(function () { $("#submitForm5").openid(); });</script>
```

Comment: I don't think this'll work, because the ID you give your form won't be the same ID when it reaches the browser (due to ASP.NET's nuances). You might want to try $('[id$="submitForm5"]') instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this?

```
$("#test.openidd").parent().openid();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').find('li.highlight span').text();
```

IE

```
$('form').unbind('submit').submit(function() {
   $id.val($('form').find("li.highlight span").text());
   });
$('form').submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since ASP.NET modify the **form**'s id, you can still get the **form** element by using **closest**. In this code, you get the **test.openidd**'s closest elemet called *form* which would be the form itself.

```
$('#test.openidd').closest('form').unbind('submit').submit(function() {
   $id.val($('#test.openidd').closest('form').find("li.highlight span").text());
   });
$('#test.openidd').closest('form').submit();
```